# Is there a way in Python/BeautifulSoup to select a particular line within a list of similar lines?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Sorry for the confusing title. I'm a complete beginner in Python and don't even know the language for asking this question.

I'm trying to do some data scrubbing of the website Box Office Mojo. I'm looking to create a csv file that pulls the table for each countries top box office hits for each year (see https://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/austria/yearly/?yr=2019&p=.htm

I've been able to use BeautifulSoup to grab a particular page and parse it:

```
pip install bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

##Creating a variable for the URL I want to use
my_url = 'https://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/austria/yearly/?yr=2019&p=.htm'

uReq(my_url)
### Opening up connecting, grabbing the page, closing the connection
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read() ###Don't run page_html because it may crash the client
uClient.close()
##Using BeuatifulSoup to read the html page and parsing it
page_soup = soup(page_html,"html.parser")
```

I've been able to isolate the particular line of html that I want to grab the information from:

```
container_odd = page_soup.findAll("tr", {"bgcolor":"#ffffff"})
container_even = page_soup.findAll("tr", {"bgcolor":"#f4f4ff"})
```

I can see that it's grabbed the text I want and can get it without all the html formatting.

```
>>>>container_even[0]
<tr bgcolor="#f4f4ff"><td align="center"><font size="2">2</font></td>
<td><font size="2">How to Train Your Dragon: The Hidden World</font></td>
<td><font size="2">UPI</font></td>
<td align="right"><font size="2"><b>$2,701,010</b></font></td>
<td align="center"><font size="2">2/8</font></td>
</tr>
```

```
>>> container_odd[0].text
'1\nCaptain Marvel\nDisney\n$3,221,398\n3/7\n'
```

I can also call the first 'td item'(I don't know what to call this) in the row:

```
>>> container_odd[0].td.text
'1'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to pull that second 'td item' in the row, i.e., 'Captain Marvel'.

What I want to do now is create a loop that will pull each individual td item from each row in container_even/odd to put in a list.

So, I want a rank_list to contain '1, 2, 3, 4...' (Or rather '1,3,5...' and '2,4,6...' because of the code in this case)

and a title list to contain 'Captain Marvel, How to train your dragon....'

What I can't figure out is how to pull that second 'td item' and then how to loop across that item in each row?

I've tried to pull at least the rank item list:

```
    rank  = td[]

    print("rank: " + rank)
```

But just got a syntax error

```
  File "scraper.py", line 25
    rank  = td[]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help getting the loop created or at least figuring out how to pull that second td item would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code in the comments:

> > > container_odd[0].text
> > >       '1\nCaptain Marvel\nDisney\n$3,221,398\n3/7\n'

You should be able to iterate over the "container_odd" object and get all of the rows that way using a for loop. For example:

```
for line in container_odd:
    raw_text = line.text
    content_list = raw_text.split('\n')
    print(content_list)
```

The "line" object will be each row of the "container_odd" object, the "raw_text" will look just like what you've pulled out (what I'm showing in the comments), and by splitting it for each '\n' character you will have a list matching the table that you've pulled.

To save this to a csv, try the following:

```
def my_csv_writer(text):
    with open(*full\\path\\filename.csv*, 'a+') as file:
        file.write(text)
        file.write('\n')

for line in container_odd:
    raw_text = line.text
    content_list = raw_text.replace(',','').split('\n')
    write_text = ','.join(content_list)
    my_csv_writer(write_text)
```

The function will serve as your "writing" function and when you do your for loop and call the writing function you can write text to a file one line at a time.

Comment: Hey Jacob. You are great!

So I through in your code and added 

````
print(content_list)
````

It shot out 
```
['25', 'Welcome to Marwen', 'UPI', '$7,611', '3/29', '']
```
which is definitely getting closer! I was hoping it would print the whole list of 1,3,5...

For my end product, what I'm hoping to do is create a csv file that has the following headers: country, year, rank, movie title, and gross. I'm working on a project about soft-power projection in International Relations and want to show how many US/Russian/Chinese films make in a given year in a given country.

Comment: Try and add the print statement ```print(content_list)``` inside of the for loop so that the command is repeated. It sounds like you added the command without an indentation, because it should print every line like you describe. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Not at all, that's how we learn. Ok, give me a second and I'll edit my answer to include the new code that will let you put this into a file. Shouldn't take too long.

Comment: It's not terribly efficient, but for a beginner who's just learning this is helpful to visualize how each piece of code works.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the with open(*full\\path\\filename.csv*, 'a+) as file: part. I put in the file destination, but I just get a syntax error pointing at C:

Comment: Whatever path you type should have quotes around it with an "r" at the front, like the following: r"C:\cygwin64\home\aname\folder1\filename.csv".

The "r" character allows you to put in raw strings instead of allowing escape characters to be translated into special characters.

Comment: Awesome. Getting even closer! So, the csv result that comes out has columns 1 and 2 correct, but because of the ',' in the gross amounts, anytime it sees a comma in the number, it creates a new row with those few digits. Is there a way to replace commas in contest_list with nothing. Perhaps, content_list.replace(",","")?

Comment: I just edited my code, let me know if that's what you're after

Comment: Beautiful! I'll replicate the code  for container_even and have that written to the csv as well. Thanks so much for your help! I've still got a few steps left (add a column that fills in the name of the country and year, which I can do, and then figure out how to create a loop that checks every country and every year on the website), but I'll try and work on that on my own for a few hours. Thanks again!

Comment: If this answer is satisfactory, be sure to mark the answer I've given as the accepted answer. I'm glad that I was able to help you out today. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use pandas as much easier. You can slice out columns if you want individual lists e.g. `list(table['Movie Title'])`

Full table:

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://www.boxofficemojo.com/intl/austria/yearly/?yr=2019&p=.htm')[2]
table.columns = table.iloc[0]
table = table.iloc[1:]
print(table)
table.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```